(kernelA<NB, NRHS, WPB, GEMM><<<numblocks, numthreads, shmem>>>())' failed: a PTX JIT compilation failed
I have two source files and one header file.
main.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <cublasdx.hpp>
#include "f2.cuh"

#define checkKernelErrors(expr)                             \
  do {                                                      \
    expr;                                                   \
                                                            \
    cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError();                 \
    if (__err != cudaSuccess) {                             \
      printf("Line %d: '%s' failed: %s\n", __LINE__, #expr, \
             cudaGetErrorString(__err));                    \
      abort();                                              \
    }                                                       \
  } while (0)


template<const int NB, const int NRHS, const int WPB, class GEMM>
__global__
void kernelA(){
    extern __shared__ double sdata[];    
    kernelB<GEMM, NB, WPB, cublasdx::col_major, cublasdx::col_major, cublasdx::col_major>();
}

int main(){
    constexpr int NB=32, numthreads=128, NRHS=32, WPB=4;
    using GEMM = decltype(cublasdx::Size<NB, NB, NB>()
            + cublasdx::Precision<double>()
            + cublasdx::LeadingDimension<NB, NB, NB>()
            + cublasdx::Type<cublasdx::type::real>()
            + cublasdx::Arrangement<cublasdx::col_major, cublasdx::col_major>()
            + cublasdx::Function<cublasdx::function::MM>()
            + cublasdx::SM<800>()
            + cublasdx::Block()
            + cublasdx::BlockDim<numthreads>());
    int numblocks=1;
    size_t shmem = sizeof(double)*1;
    checkKernelErrors((kernelA<NB, NRHS, WPB, GEMM><<<numblocks, numthreads, shmem>>>()));
    return 0;
}

f2.cu
#include "f2.cuh"
template<class GEMM, const int NB, const int WPB, cublasdx::arrangement LA, cublasdx::arrangement LB, cublasdx::arrangement LC>
__device__  void kernelB(){;}

f2.cuh
#include <cublasdx.hpp>
template<class GEMM, const int NB, const int WPB, cublasdx::arrangement LA, cublasdx::arrangement LB, cublasdx::arrangement LC>
__device__  void kernelB();

Here is my compilation info.
/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/bin/nvcc -c f2.cu -o f2.o -ccbin /depot/gcc-9.2.0/bin/g++ -gencode arch=compute_80,code=compute_80 -m64 -Xptxas -dlcm=cg -lineinfo -maxrregcount=255 --threads 0 -std=c++17 --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DCUBLASDX_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_SM_80 -O3  -I/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/include -I/cuda-samples-12.0/Common -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//external/cutlass/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/example/ -I../tools/  
nvcc warning : incompatible redefinition for option 'compiler-bindir', the last value of this option was used
/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/bin/nvcc -c main.cu -o gemm.o -ccbin /depot/gcc-9.2.0/bin/g++ -gencode arch=compute_80,code=compute_80 -m64 -Xptxas -dlcm=cg -lineinfo -maxrregcount=255 --threads 0 -std=c++17 --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DCUBLASDX_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_SM_80 -O3  -I/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/include -I/cuda-samples-12.0/Common -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//external/cutlass/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/example/ -I../tools/ 
nvcc warning : incompatible redefinition for option 'compiler-bindir', the last value of this option was used
/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/bin/nvcc -I/depot/cuda/cuda-12.2/include -I/cuda-samples-12.0/Common -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//external/cutlass/include/ -I/cuda/nvidia-mathdx-24.08.0/nvidia/mathdx/24.08//include/cublasdx/example/ -I../tools/ -ccbin /depot/gcc-9.2.0/bin/g++ -gencode arch=compute_80,code=compute_80 -m64 -Xptxas -dlcm=cg -lineinfo -maxrregcount=255 --threads 0 -std=c++17 --expt-relaxed-constexpr -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DCUBLASDX_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_SM_80 -O3  -L/depot/cuda/cuda-12.0/lib64 -lcublas -lnvToolsExt f2.o gemm.o -o gemm

When I run the binary, it shows the following error.
Line 38: '(kernelA<NB, NRHS, WPB, GEMM><<<numblocks, numthreads, shmem>>>())' failed: a PTX JIT compilation failed
Abort (core dumped)

If I directly write the kernelB in f2.cuh or main.cu, there won't be any errors.

I see no evidence of compilation with relocatable device code with device linking, which is necessary for your project setup (device code linking across compilation unit boundaries).  I don't know why you are not getting a link error at project build time, but that would appear to be the proximal reason for the issue.  Putting the device code into the same compilation unit fixes the issue is consistent with that signature.  There are numerous questions on the cuda tag discussing this and what to do.
